# How to return a specifies field (arrive_date) via HttpMessageNotReadableException.class

Tags: java, spring

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public UnreadableSMS handleBusinessException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.getMessage())

return ex.getMessage();
```

}

Out_Put: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "203-03-03": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '203-03-03' could not be parsed at index 0; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "203-03-03": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '203-03-03' could not be parsed at index 0
at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 17, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.gdce.declaration.form.web.dtos.PassengerDeclarationFormDto["arrival_date"])

Comment: Can you please provide stacktrace of error in a formatted way. And it would be good to have example of desired output.

Comment: the year from that date is `203` (3 digits long). Perhaps your pattern you're trying to deserialize to is something like `yyyy-mm-dd` therefore the discrepancy, Is this 3-digit year something you need to support in your app?